# HTTPS connection valid with Chrome and not valid with Firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl

I have a hard time understand why my certificate for SSL connection is directly valid with Chrome where it isn't with Firefox 9.

Test URL here : https://www.tkwk.be

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Jk_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SSL server is misconfigured. You need to include the intermediate certificates in your installation. The basics of this are as follows:

You go to a CA that a root certificate A in your browser. You give them a certificate signing request and $$ and they return you a signed certificate Z plus zero or more intermediate certificates B, C, D .... These certificates form a certificate chain, with A signing B, B signing C, and so on. Your certificate Z is last one in the chain.

You configure your SSL server with your private key, and and also the certificates B, C, D, ..., Z. You don't need A.

In your case, A is GlobalSign, B is GlobalSign Extended Validation CA G2 and Z is www.tkwk.be. You are missing certificate B from your side. To see how it should look, go to https://www.globalsign.com/ssl and examine the certificate chain